# how to merge two JSON, where, one JSON will be having actual response and other will providing configuration

Tags: javascript, angular

I have `actual Response` as below:

```
{
    "ClassifierId": "abc1",
    "results": [{
            "Input": "Input data1",
            "Score": 0.9,
            "Prediction": "Prediction1"
        },
        {
            "Input": "Input data2",
            "Score": 0.1,
            "Prediction": "Prediction1"
        }
    ]
}
```

and need to bind in `config-json` as below:

```
[{
    "type": "",
    "row": [{
            "header": "",
            "col": [{
                "data": [{

                        "label": "Score",
                        "valueMapping": "@^results[i].Score",
                        "displayType": "vertical"
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "Prediction",
                        "valueMapping": "@^results[i].Prediction",
                        "displayType": "vertical"
                    }
                ]
            }]
        },
        {
            "header": "",
            "col": [{
                "data": [{
                    "label": "Text",
                    "valueMapping": "@^results[i].Input",
                    "displayType": "vertical"
                }]
            }]
        }
    ]
}]
```

My Actual response may differ from api response, but i need to configure only config JSON.  '"@^results[i].***"' are the respective value from the actual JSON. '@^' is used for identify the mapping values.

I have tried several ways, but unfortunately didn't get any luck, Please guide/direct/ help

Comment: You can push the response object in `config-json` array.

Comment: could u pls. elaborate?

Comment: what is the expected output?